# Python, Instance has no attribute

Tags: python

So I'm currently trying to learn python and I'm following this guide on youtube. It put me through this. But When I run it I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/test.py", line 29
    app = Application(root)
  File "C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'create_widgets'
```

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
""" GUI with click counter """

  def __init__(self, master):
    """ Init the frame """
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.button_clicks =0 #Counts the button clicks
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create button widget """
        self.button = Button(self)
        self.button["text"] = "Total Clicks: 0"
        self.button["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button.grid()

        def update_count(self):
            """ Increase click count """
            self.button_clicks += 1
            self.button["text"] = "Total Clicks: " + str(self.button_clicks)

root = Tk()
root.title("Button Counter")
root.geometry("200x100")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation in your file?

Comment: You need to indent the whole `def __init__` by one indentation level to ensure that the method belongs to the type.

Comment: you’re actually defining functions inside functions. have your `def`s at the same indentation level and all will be good.

Comment: you simply has to unindent each def statement (including func body).

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias commented, the problem is in your indentation. Python requires proper indentation, as that's how it determines the beginning and ending of blocks.

Here is how your code should look:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI with click counter """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Init the frame """
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.button_clicks =0 #Counts the button clicks
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create button widget """
        self.button = Button(self)
        self.button["text"] = "Total Clicks: 0"
        self.button["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button.grid()

    def update_count(self):
        """ Increase click count """
        self.button_clicks += 1
        self.button["text"] = "Total Clicks: " + str(self.button_clicks)

root = Tk()
root.title("Button Counter")
root.geometry("200x100")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```